# What is the counter part of Task.Run(Sub() ) for .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi I'm currently working on a project and my target framework is .NET Framework 2.0 for windows 2000. I can't use the task.Run. Is there an other option?

Comment: `Thread` and `BackGroundWorker`

Comment: The most similar method would be `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Async delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.80).aspx) and [the thread pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.80).aspx) for quick examples. The idea IAsyncResult pattern is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.80).aspx) with some good examples.

It's quite different from tasks as you do not have much of control over task scheduler, but will do the work in most of cases.